# Unable to read RSS feed using node htmlparser

Tags: node.js, rss, html-parsing, html-parser

I am trying to read slashdot rss feed using the following code:

```
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser");
var sys = require("sys");
var handler = new htmlparser.RssHandler(function (error, dom) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(dom);
});
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
parser.parseComplete("http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdotMain");
console.log(handler.dom);
sys.puts(sys.inspect(handler.dom, false, null));
```

Instead of returning array of feeds it always returns the following:

```
[ { data: 'http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdotMain',
    type: 'text' } ]
```

What is the problem ? Is something wrong in my code ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, according to the documentation of [htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser), you have to pass to the parseComplete function the raw html code of the RSS feed so, before parse the webpage, acquire the source code of that using the request module and, then, try to parse the data with htmlparser module.
Your code should look like this:

```
var request = require("request");
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser");
var sys = require("sys");
var handler = new htmlparser.RssHandler(function (error, dom) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(dom);
});
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);

request({
  uri: "http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdotMain",
}, function(error, response, body) {
   parser.parseComplete(body);
   console.log(handler.dom);
   sys.puts(sys.inspect(handler.dom, false, null));
});
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't mentions `request()` method anywhere, so where did you get it ?

Comment: I suppose that the Request module should be used because, in the documentation, it is passed the raw html code to the `parse` function. The Request module is already included in your nodejs configuration ([doc](https://github.com/request/request)) and it's allow you to get the source code of a web page. 
Technically, having the source in memory, you can use the `parse` function as reported in the documentation.